# Making a jar file runnable on other machines?

Tags: java, windows, jar

I have created jar file that performs some file operations and I need to distribute them to a few people on the network.  To my surprise though, the jar isn't runnable on their machines!  I was told that another working was able to get it to run by installing the Java developer's kit, but this isn't the best way if I need to distribute to multiple people.

What are my options here, and what are the 'best practice' solutions?  I would prefer not to install the JDK (I think I only need the JRE here but haven't tested), would I simply be able to rewrite the jar into an applet so that it could run in a browser? Or should I just pop up a link to the latest JRE version and ask that they download it?

Edit: I created the jar through eclipse(Export>Runnable Jar) and it produces a runnable jar that I can run.  When moved to another machine windows does not know what to open the file with.  It would seem I need the JRE (the java we install on our machines is just the browser plug in, not the JRE I have found.)  I was wondering if there was a way to do more work on my end to prevent this so that the end use would have it simpler (Launch4j has been suggested and is what I am moving into, or simply installing manually.)  I have taken a few classes in java but they are pure coding and never covered how a jar should be 'distributed'.

Comment: "*the jar isn't runnable on their machines*" How did you create this jar? Did you set main class which also has `public static void main(String[] args)` in it?

Comment: @Pshemo he is saying running jar on a machine where no jre/jdk present

Comment: Did the jar run on your machine? What exactly doesn't work on other machines (does nothing, error message, ...)? What OS and JRE is installed?

Comment: @user3728545 you only need a JRE to run a jar, JDK not required

Comment: If your code uses some functionality from  `tools.jar` or, for example, `javac` tool, you must install JDK on these computers, otherwise - JRE is ok.

Comment: There is a way to embed a JRE in the jar file, but it's not pretty.

Comment: @Sanjeev "*he is saying running jar on a machine where no jre/jdk present*" where did exactly OP say it? From what I see OP knows that it's JRE which is required and would simply "*prefer not to install the JDK*".

Comment: The jar file is runnable as a standalone on my machine, it also runs on others if the JRE is installed.  I can certainly require that a user needs the JRE but this is a simple program and would therefore require and IT to approve the install.  This isn't a problem for this small case but since a lot of the higher end stuff is self taught I want to make sure I could understand and make a correct decision.

Comment: @Pshemo - The OP says he's "not sure" if a JRE is sufficient or not, which tells me he's not too savvy on any of this stuff.

Comment: @HotLicks If I understand English correctly (it is not my native language :/) *not being sure if something is sufficient* means *I know that something is necessary, but I am not sure if it is enough*. Based on that I assume that OP knows that JRE is needed here, so (s)he wouldn't ask this question if it was not installed. I suspect that problem may be that JRE could be not installed correctly, or its versions doesn't match, or maybe some other reasons. That is why I would like to know how OP did create jar (on what Java version for instance) and knowing how OP is trying to run it would be nice

Comment: I agree that the OP needs to give us more info, but I find that it's very difficult to underestimate the knowledge of the OP in such situations.

Comment: @user3728545 Could you [[edit]] your question and make it clear what problem you are facing? As it is written now we are not sure how did you create your jar, how are you trying to run it and what environment you are using (if there is JRE installed or not - you just said that if there is JDK it works, but you skipped part about results if JRE is installed). Your comment kind of clarifies few things, but not everyone is reading comments so you should place all relevant informations in your questions, like what errors do you see when you can't run jar.

Answer (score 5):

Java programs require a JRE to run. That's true of runnable jars as well as applets.

You can use jnlp to automatically download a JRE for you, but since applets and webstarts have been all but deprecated, that's probably not the way to go.

You can tell your users that they need to have a JRE installed on their machines before running your program. This is pretty reasonable as most people have a JRE, but it can get complicated if your users have an older version of the JRE and you're compiling for a newer version.

You can also bundle a JRE with your program using something like [JWrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/) or [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). This will guarantee that your program works on any client machine, but it means you have to create separate versions for each operating system, and the download size will be vastly increased since you have to include the JRE with your project.

There aren't any real best practices to help you, unfortunately. In my experience most smaller projects simply require a JRE to be installed, and most big projects (like the games by Puppy Games) bundle a JRE inside the program itself. It's really up to you.

Comment: webstart is deprecated?

Comment: I mention the applet option as we install 'java' on all our machines, what that means is a bit vague.  I had assumed that it only installs it for the browser and I was hoping if I push it through that I would be able to use what is already installed.  When we 'install java' what is it installing? It must be some kind of JRE but I think it is just for browsers?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Applets and webstarts now require you to either have a paid certificate or for your users to change their security settings. Either way they display big scary messages to the users, and it's unclear how much longer browsers will support them. They aren't deprecated, but it's a bad idea to start using them now.

Comment: @user3728545 I have no idea what's installed on your machines. I would guess that you have the JRE installed, as installing it only for a browser doesn't really make any sense. A simple test would be to go to a command prompt and type "java -version" and see what happens.

Comment: @KalpeshSoni I wouldn't give that link out as a recommendation anymore. It errors out on me. Plus it depends on the browser plugin, which is different than what will run the jar. Best to just use the command prompt.

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Yes, those are the messages. Not sure why you're posting them though.

Comment: so others can see what we are talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

may you are looking for something like this :

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

but i dont think this is best practice

Answer (score -1):

you can always write a web app - everybody has a browser

if you want java code to run you need jdk/jre - you could give a zip file containing jar and jre as a clunky way to "install" your app

jnlp or webstart can help clients load the right version of jre